# MarionetteJS: updating all ItemViews in a CompositeView after a 'change' event in the DOM

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

After I change an input text field that corresponds to a single attribute in an `ItemView`, I update all models in my `CompositeView`.

The update works fine in the models, but only the ItemView corresponding to the last edited input text field displays new attributes in the DOM, as it's the only element in the `CompositeView` that's getting its `onRender` method called:

```
   onRender: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
```

I want to call the `onRender()` function again in all the `ItemViews` inside the `CompositeView`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but here goes

```
var childViews = compositeView.children._views;
_.each(childViews, function(childView){
    childView.render();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using what I mentioned in my answer. I'll try this too.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe i didnt understand your question properly but the problem with the method in your answer is that the only itemview that will update is the one whose model has changed, and not all of the itemviews inside the compositeview

Answer (score 1):

After reading what appears in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572509/how-to-access-a-composite-view-from-an-item-view-instance-in-backbone-marionette), and the checking out the documentation. I figured that I would try simply using a `change` event listener in the `ItemView`.

```
myItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        /*bind change event, will get onRender fired when the probability gets updated
        this.model.bind('change', this.onRender);
        error: 'cannot call' Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined
        TODO: figure out WHY this is an error but this.render is OK*/

        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    }
```

Mysteriously, `onRender()` fails, but `render()` does the job. Now I want to figure out why.

Comment: `onRender` is called after `render`. Render is a backbone method that marionette has implemented for you. In order for marionette to still give you some flexibility, theyve provided `onBeforeRender` and `onRender` so that you can customize their default behaviour. These two methods do nothing unless you provide them with functionality, only `render` actually updates the view by default

Comment: also, just so ya know, you can also listen to ALL change events in a collection so if one model changes you can update all of your itemviews. `something.listenTo(someCollection, 'change', function(){console.log('an attribute on a model just changed');});`

Comment: @Scott: Thanks! That clarifies a lot.